# Show parent name in child view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

something what should really be easy and I can't get it to work...
I have a Relation which has_many Contacts and Contact belongs_to Relation. Now I want to show the relation name in the contact index view. In the contacts controller I have this:

```
@contacts = Contact.paginate :page     => params[:page],
                             :include  => :relations,
                             :per_page => 10,
                             :order    => "last_name"
```

Now I expect in the index view to be able to use this:

```
<%= contact.relation.name %>
```

But it returns a `undefined method "name" for nil:NilClass` error? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have at least one `Contact` object that doesn't have an associated `Relation` object, which is why it's trying to call `.name` on a nil value.

You can try doing something like this temporarily to see if you have some Contacts without Relations:

```
<%= contact.relation.name rescue "MISSING NAME" %>
```

and see what gets displayed.

Comment: Thanks! the relation_id was empty in the table, so the problem is in the create, but my code for the index view was OK then, phew :-)

Comment: I forgot to set relation_id as attr_accessible.